# Getting only one value when appending NSString to NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

Below is my code. When Looping over an `NSArray` of `NSDictionary` objects and trying to append to an array I keeping an `NSLog` which shows the correct result, but the result `NSArray` only contains the last record.

```
for (NSDictionary *entry in entries) {
    NSString* projID = [entry objectForKey:@"NM_PROJECT"];
    NSArray *projectNames = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:projID,nil];
    _projectpicker.delegate = self;
    _projectpicker.dataSource = self;

    NSLog(@"Error : %@", projID);
}
```

Log Result:
Test1
test2
test3
test4

When appending to `NSArray` (Projectnames) I was getting last data..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting:

```
_projectpicker.delegate = self;
_projectpicker.dataSource = self;
```

inside a loop doesn't make much sense. You don't need to do it multiple times.

While the other answers accurately describe what you're doing wrong with the array, your current requirement can be achieved more succinctly using KVC:

```
NSArray *projectNames = [entries valueForKey:@"NM_PROJECT"];
```

(then you don't need your own loop at all)

Comment: Could you be more elaborate Wain

Comment: Thank you Wain.. Its describes me a Lot.. Thank you for ur help

Answer (score 5):

Every each loop iteration you initialise new array, you don't add new object to the array.
To do that you have to create NSMutableArray before loop and add object inside loop:

```
NSMutableArray *projectNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSDictionary *entry in entries) {
            NSString* projID = [entry objectForKey:@"NM_PROJECT"];
            [projectNames addObject: projID];
            _projectpicker.delegate = self;
            _projectpicker.dataSource = self;
            NSLog(@"Error : %@", projID);
}
NSLog(@"Array : %@", projectNames);
```

Comment: Greg Thanks for quick response but as it is a Picker view and one of the drop down name is projectNames Which is NSarray. So I cannot modify again to NSmutuable Array..

Comment: After enumeration you can convert NSMutableArray to NSArray. You cannot add now objects to NSArray.

Comment: You don't need to convert. A mutable array is a type of array. If you want to ensure it is immutable, just do `[projectNames copy]`

Answer (score 3):

Keep `alloc` statement outside of your for loop and use a `NSMutableArray` and then keep on adding to this array as and when required from inside the for loop.

```
NSMutableArray *projectNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for(...)
{
    [projectNames addObject: anyObject];
}
```

Comment: Vikram Thanks for quick response but as it is a Picker view and one of the drop down name is projectNames Which is NSarray. So I cannot modify again to NSmutuable Array..

Comment: Thanks Vikram Even u helped me to some extent